# Check if two property of a nested document are equal in mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I have a `user.expenses` collection like this

```
{
    userId: ObjectId("62f332b93753ac926ff6ac62"),
    expenses: [ 
        { 
            name: 'electricity',
            assigned: 400,
            given: 400,
        },
        {
            name: 'restaurant',
            assigned: 2100,
            given: 0,
        }
    ]
}
```

I will get `userId` and `expenses.name`(electricity) from the request. I need to check if the `user.expenses` collection has any `expenses` document whose name is `electricity` and `assigned` is not equal to `given`.

I used `$elemMatch` and could check if there are any embedded documents whose `name` is `electricity`.

```
db.user.expenses.find({
    userId: ObjectId('62f332b93753ac926ff6ac62'),
    expenses: {
        $elemMatch: {
            name: 'electricity',
        },
    },
});
```

### **EDIT**

I also tried to use `$where`. But it only can be applied to the top-level document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- you cant do it with query operators because you want to reference a field but you can do it with aggregate operators and `$filter`
- filter the array and keep only if `electricity` and `assigned!=given`
- keep the document if at least one sub-document was `electricity` with `assigned!=given`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62fbd28e78a49d8782851480)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$ne": 
       [{"$filter": 
           {"input": "$expenses",
            "cond": 
             {"$and": 
               [{"$eq": ["$$this.name", "electricity"]},
                 {"$ne": ["$$this.assigned", "$$this.given"]}]}}}, []]}}}])
```

Comment: I only need the documents where `expenses.name` == 'electricity' and `expenses.assigned` !== `expenses.given`. But this query is returning all documents.

Comment: i know, i left it like that so you could add the filter the way you needed it, or keep the fitlered array, i wasnt sure what is the expected output, i updated the query, i added the filter, this query doesnt change the document, just keeps it or not

Comment: Excellent! It worked. But the funny part is I don't know how it works. 